# Bus error 10: Trying to initialize pthread running Symfony 4 CLI command with PHP 7.2

Tags: php, symfony, pthreads, symfony4, php-7.2

I'm trying to initialize a thread from a Symfony 4 command from CLI, but getting "Bus error: 10."

```php
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Thread;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class LaunchMyAppCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('app:launch-myapp');
        $this->setDescription('Launches app.');
        $this->setHelp('This launches app...');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $thread = new class extends Thread {
            public function run() {
                file_put_contents('/tmp/myapp.log', 'My entry', FILE_APPEND);
            }
        };

        $thread->start();
    }
}
```

```
$ php bin/console app:launch-myapp
Bus error: 10
```

I've tried to copy the initialization part out to a seperate file for debug purpose, which worked. So pthreads seems to be installed correctly. Also, according to phpinfo() thread safety is enabled.

```php
<?php

$thread = new class extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        file_put_contents('/tmp/home.log', 'My entry', FILE_APPEND);
    }
};

$thread->start();
```